# Have to call a method in interval of 15 min, 30min 1 hr ,2 hr and 5 hr to update content. Best way

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification, background-fetch

I have to call a method to update the db which exposed by the some sdk, Now I have confusion to choose concept to do this.
Should I go with :

- `UILocalNotification`

  - `Background Fetch`
  - `Timer` (Won't be good idea I guess)

Please, suggest.

Comment: what data are you planning to add to the db on the update?  Do you need location data for instance?

Comment: it's just refrsh method exposed by sdk, rest they will do.

Comment: reason to downvote? just wanted to know people choice, I am aware of concept.

Comment: this very demotivating that after down vote, it should be commented for reason of being down vote then only I can understand it more clearly. If I would have be knowing this question then probably I would have not been posted this question to ask y'all.

Comment: When you want to update the db when app is in background or app is in Killed State.

Comment: When app is in background. If app is killed then no issue I am refreshing it foreground. But It should do in background as well. I started to handle via UILocalNotification. Please, let me know if this approach is not fine

Comment: It has to execute when App is in foreground as well.

Comment: LocalNotification is a great way to go.

Comment: But User might confuse to when we ask for authorization, as this implementation intended to update some data, not to notify user in any way regarding that. is that make sense?